# Can I preserve the view of the design query in editor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am modifying some stored procedures. I select the SQL and right-click and click Design Query in Editor to see the graphical view of the logic.  I find this very useful, versus just viewing the raw SQL.

Anyway, every time I do this, the view reverts to a small window and none of the tables are in the place I put them before.  I'm wondering if there is a way to preserve the view in the Query Editor so I don't have to re-do it every singe time I want to see the view.  I looked around SQL Server and didn't find anything obvious.  I researched this too, but I didn't find anything on this topic.

Comment: please add screenshot

Comment: You can only save database diagram.. not query.. well you could save the "query" as database diagram

Comment: Thanks.  How do I save the Query as a Database Diagram?  I have a bunch of Views.  I think you are referring to something different, right.

Comment: I am assuming you mean right clicking on a view and choosing design? You can't do this with a procedure. You could save a database diagram which is essentially what that window is when designing a view. I never use the graphical tool for views myself. The queries it makes can be awful.